# Creating a shared directory with nginx file server

Tags: linux, nginx

I have dozen of log files from my server. I wanted to share them over web server, keeping it as simple as possible. I set up authentication for nginx web server, and tried to create symlinks to log files my Python script is storing in dedicated folder in my `home` directory. First i tried to set this directory as nginx root, but i learned that it's a bad idea, so i decided to create symlinks in default nginx root directory, but it didn't work either.

I thought that maybe synchronizing files across both folders may work, but that honestly seems like a huge overkill for such a simple task.

How else should i approach this?

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0):

By default, nginx will try to prevent you from an insecure setup where you serve files outside of your nginx root. See here for how to fix: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157022/make-nginx-follow-symlinks

Second, you need to ensure that the nginx user can list and read the files. (generally, via group permissions.)

It would actually be much better to store the files under the nginx root, and modify your python program.